# execute batch file inside perl

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file

How could i execute a windows batch file inside perl ??

Here is the batch file

```
@echo off 2>nul (>>test.csv echo off) && ( set ret=0) || (set ret=1)
@echo.%ret%>test.txt
```

The above code checks if a file named test.csv is open or not. If open, it wil return 1 or else it wil return 0. I have saved this result in a test.txt file.

If i use any html code inside of a perl file, i use this to exclude the html code.

```
print <<end_of_file; 
     <html>
          html code inside this
    </html>
end_of_file
```

Can someone suggest me how to include the batch file inside a perl code in similar fashion.

Comment: This looks more than a bit misguided, but if opening in append mode really does test if the file is open elsewhere, then there is no reason you can't do that in Perl code. Or, put the batch file in a known location and use `system`. The problem is, if I open a file in Notepad, this test fails.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür, Re "The problem is, if I open a file in Notepad, this test fails.", I don't think the OP needs a general solution.

Answer (score 4):

Just as with HTML,

```
<<'end_of_file'
@echo off 2>nul (>>test.csv echo off) && ( set ret=0) || (set ret=1)
@echo.%ret%>test.txt
end_of_file
```

I suspect your question is how to get `cmd` to execute the commands you have in a variable.

```
use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );

my $shell_commands = <<'end_of_file';
@echo off 2>nul (>>test.csv echo off) && ( set ret=0) || (set ret=1)
@echo.%ret%>test.txt
end_of_file

{
   pipe(local *R, local *W) or die($!);

   my $pid = open3('<&R', '>&STDOUT', '>&STDERR', 'cmd');
   print(W $shell_commands);
   print(W "exit\n");  
   close(W);
   waitpid($pid, 0);
}
```

By why would you want to use `cmd` to check if you can open a file?! Use the following instead:

```
my $ret = open(my $fh, '>>', test.csv) ? 0 : 1;
open(my $result_fh, '>', 'test.txt') or die($!);
print($result_fh "$ret\n");
```

By the way, in both versions, a permission error will result in the file being reported as open, and it will report an open file as closed if it was opened shared.

Comment: @ikegami- this has confused me a bit. wat exactly does the 2nd and 3rd code do ?

Comment: Don't you want to execute the batch "file"? That's what the second snippet does. The third is the Perl equivalent of your batch file.

Comment: @ikegami- Yea, so i have to write all these code to execute. i am a newbie in perl and using windows batch file inside perl code is confusing me more.

Comment: You need a shell to execute the batch "file", and you have to feed it the batch file somehow, so yeah, you need all that. All that just to see if `open` succeeds and store the result in a file, trivial things to do in Perl.

Comment: @ikegami- it is giving me error and i am not able to understand wat the error is. can you please suggest

Comment: I have a problem too. please suggest.

Comment: @ikegami- the function which starts with use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );
in above code of yours is giving me an error.

Comment: What error?! No, don't tell me, cause I don't care. Let me be clear: Involving a shell to check if you can open a file is a very dumb thing to do. Especially since it involves open countless files in the process. You shouldn't be using that. You should be using the code I posted at the bottom.

Comment: @Ikegami- got it. so the last code is the perl code which performs the same action as the windows batch file. so i should avoid all the earlier ones and only use this to see if the file is open or not. right >?

Comment: @ikegami- can you pls confirm the last code is correct. it doesnt work for me. i have excluded all the batch script and only used ur last code function